# heroku config on rails app suppressing logs on development env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, logging, heroku

I am working on porting a `rails 4.2` app from `linode` to `heroku`. I have the changes in a separate branch.

When I am testing the app locally, the heroku branch seems to be suppressing the logs; nothing gets written to the `log/development.log` file. The logging functionality works fine when I switch over to the `master` branch.

So I have been switching between branches if I need to see the logs for any new changes I make in the application. The heroku porting is not yet complete; so that branch is not merged with `master.

Why would the heroku specific branch be suppressing the logs? What config should I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason is that you put heroku `rails_12factor` gem in your Gemfile which overwrites your development.rb settings . Try moving that gem to `production` block in your Gemfile and try again

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the case. Moving the `rails_12factor` gem to `production` block fixed the issue.